# Firefox html5 only 360p

Tags: firefox, html5

This got fixed with the recent firefox patch 38.0.1!

I already tried this [Only 360p on Youtube with HTML5](https://superuser.com/questions/903676/only-360p-on-youtube-with-html5)
but it did not work.
[image]

I also tried restoring default firefox (deleting all addons and setting settings to default) which did not help)

edit: Dash seems to be not supported (h264 codec is set to always active)

[image]

Is there any other option I could try?

System:
Win 8.1 64bit
Firefox 38.0

Comment: Firefox 38.0 on Win8 with MSE & H.264 disabled? Strange. Under Plugins check whether OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc. is set to Always Activate. Did you also check all the about:config entries as mentioned in [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/903715/138343)?

Comment: h264 is always active and I checked all your attributes (and needed to add `media.mediasource.youtubeonly` on my own). On my workplace (which is Win7 64bit) I saw that FF can play youtbe videos in 1080p with 60fps in html5. That's why I wanted to try it at home.

Comment: "h264 is always active" - Not according to Youtube apparently, which is not detecting it for some reason. If you check any HD video's Stats for nerds, is DASH supported?

Comment: no apparently dash is not supported, added a picture to make that clear

Comment: Are you logged into Youtube by any chance? If so check under settings whether "I have a slow connection. Never play higher-quality video" is enabled by mistake. if not, for testing purposes can you uninstall Flash temporarily?

Comment: Before I uninstalled I tried another video: This video plays in 1080p : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FflcA85zcOM and DASH says yes. Then I uninstalled Flash but nothing changed. I tried another video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpUI-KXz7xc This one works with 1080p60. I do not get why some work and others do not. The one in the screenshot was the one I tried on my workplace with 1080p60 (or50?) just fine. And yt/html5 still says that mse & h264 are disabled

Comment: You mean the 60fps HFR videos? I have no problems viewing any of these so perhaps Youtube is not feeding those to you based on certain criteria like connection speed or whatever. MSE & H.264 showing up as disabled is odd though. Is it possible for you to back up your profile, uninstall and reinstall Firefox, then try Youtube with no third-party add-ons and plugins installed?

Comment: @Wandang IMHO some videos just do not have that option due to the original uploaded file. Still no reason why youtube doesn't detect your H264 capabilities. Have you tried Google Chrome instead? It's actually the only method to get a decent up-to-date flash.

Comment: On my workplace I have openh264 v1.3 instead of 1.4... Maybe that is the reason. Gonna try that at home