# Only 360p resolution on YouTube with Iceweasel on Debian 8 (Jessie)

Tags: youtube, html5, high-definition, debian-jessie, iceweasel

With a fresh installation of Debian 8 (KDE) using Iceweasel I can only play YouTube videos with 360p resolution and lower.

*(Can't post screenshot due to low reputation :/)*

There is a solution that works with Fedora 20 (https://superuser.com/a/903715/233157) but not with Debian 8. If I apply the proposed changes that are:

- Requesting html5 playback on *(Can't post link due to low reputation :/)*
- in about:config turning on

  - *media.mediasource.enabled*
  - *media.mediasource.youtubeonly*
  - *media.mediasource.mp4.enabled*
  - *media.mediasource.webm.enabled*
  - *media.fragmented-mp4.exposed*
  - *media.fragmented-mp4.ffmpeg.enabled*

I am able to switch to higher resolutions but the video frame remains black. The sound works fine.

*(Can't post screenshot due to low reputation :/)*

**How can I play high definition videos on YouTube on Debian 8 using Iceweasel?**

Comment: If images would make the question more useful, add a comment with links at an image sharing service, like imgur.com.  Address a comment to me with @fixer1234, and I'll be happy to embed them.  re: 1st bullet, include the additional link in the comment.  You already have your own answer, but this looks like a generally useful post and you might get some more rep from it.  If you can no longer capture problem images due to the fix, delete the screenshot references (the edit will also bump the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Iceweasel to 38.2.1esr-1~deb8u1 resolved the issue. Out of the box only 720p is available but activating mediasource extentions as described above (not all steps necessary) unlocked the 1080p resolution.